# Unity_PlayerController_Problem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm learning Unity and use the website Unity Learn(https://learn.unity.com) Now I'm make Prototype 3 Lesson 2.2 and have a problem with OnCollisionEnter because it registers the Ground Tag but not the Obstacle Tag (I've checked: My Obstacle has a Tag). There are no erroes in the console.

Please help me.
Thank you.

Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody playerRb;

    public float jumpForce = 10f;
    public float gravityModifier;

    private bool isOnGround = true;

    public bool gameOver = false;

    public GameObject obstaclePrefab;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        playerRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        Physics.gravity *= gravityModifier;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isOnGround)
        {
            playerRb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
            isOnGround = false;
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Obstacle"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Game Over");
            gameOver = true;
        }

        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            isOnGround = true;
        } 
    }
}
```

I've checked if my Obstacle Prefab has a Tag but it have a Tag called "Obstacle". There are no erroes in the console. When I've made an else-block, it have registered collisions with the Ground but haven't made the code with the Obstacle.

Comment: you'll need to show pictures of setup [mcve] as most are not going to watch a tutorial and try work out what step you missed. so show your player and components, your obstacle and component all the bits that make up relevant information as to why this isnt working.

Comment: I'd suggest that you check the spelling (it's easy to make a typo) and examine your obstacle instances to actually have the tag (sometimes you change things and don't apply to prefab/change the standard value)

Comment: Check the spelling like mentioned above. Also, ensure the GameObject with the collider has the tag and not its parent or child. Pictures would help us a lot